# Unhandled rejection Error, When installing react-global-configuration package

Tags: reactjs, npm, config, react-fullstack

I was trying to install the react-global-configuration package using the below command.

```
npm install react-global-configuration
```

But it gives below error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, close

npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

Can anyone help me with this?